# redirect 301 - One htaccess for multiple websites

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having one htaccess file that is used by multiple websites and have trouble redirecting directories for one specific domain only.

Example:
I would like
www.website.com/folder to redirect 301 to www.website.com/NEWfolder
but at the same time 
NOT redirect www.website-2.com/folder.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, yes. 

You need to compare the URL with regular expressions in your htaccess file and create some rewrite conditions.

Comment: I guess like this? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/success-mapping-multiple-domains-to-different-folders-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all these sites are served from the same document root, you'll need mod_rewrite's `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable to narrow down the site that you want to focus on:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /NEWfolder/$1 [L,R=301]
```